# Probability of a sum S using X dice each with different Y faces

Tags: excel, vba, probability

I'm trying to write a code in VBA that returns the probability of getting a sum S rolling X dice each with Y sides(es: rolling 1 six-sided die + 2 eight-sided dice + 2 four-sided dice).

Given my poor experience and knowledge of VBA, I've written an ugly code that covers X <= 5; what I'd like to obtain is to find a simpler, better, more optimized way to use an arbitrarily large X.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Somma()


Dim dado1, dado2, dado3, dado4, dado5 As Integer
Dim inp As Double
Dim prob As Long

som = Sheets("Prob").Range("d11").Value

'set each variable to each die's sides
dado1 = Sheets("Prob").Range("d2").Value
dado2 = Sheets("Prob").Range("d3").Value
dado3 = Sheets("Prob").Range("d4").Value
dado4 = Sheets("Prob").Range("d5").Value
dado5 = Sheets("Prob").Range("d6").Value

prob = 0

If Sheets("Prob").Range("d7").Value = 2 Then 'how many dice are used
For d1 = 1 To dado1
    For d2 = 1 To dado2
        If d1 + d2 >= inp Then prob = prob + 1
    Next d2
Next d1

Sheets("Prob").Range("d14").Value = prob


Else
If Sheets("Prob").Range("d7").Value = 3 Then
For d1 = 1 To dado1
    For d2 = 1 To dado2
        For d3 = 1 To dado3
            If d1 + d2 + d3 >= inp Then prob = prob + 1
        Next d3
    Next d2
Next d1
Sheets("Prob").Range("d14").Value = prob

Else
If Sheets("Prob").Range("d7").Value = 4 Then
For d1 = 1 To dado1
    For d2 = 1 To dado2
        For d3 = 1 To dado3
            For d4 = 1 To dado4
                 If d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 >= inp Then prob = prob + 1
            Next d4
        Next d3
    Next d2
Next d1
Sheets("Prob").Range("d14").Value = prob

Else
For d1 = 1 To dado1
    For d2 = 1 To dado2
        For d3 = 1 To dado3
            For d4 = 1 To dado4
                For d5 = 1 To dado5
                 If d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5 >= inp Then prob = prob + 1
                Next d5
            Next d4
        Next d3
    Next d2
Next d1
Sheets("Prob").Range("d14").Value = prob

End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

This works perfectly, but, as stated before:

1. it's ugly
2. it's limited.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit for [codereview.se]?

Comment: New to this forum.. should I repost there?

Comment: I'm not sure if reposting or having it migrated is better, maybe someone else can chime in?

Comment: Since this code is working, it would be a better fit on Code Review.

Comment: A simple sum of dice problem (without wrinkles such as omitting the least two dice or only taking the highest 3 or stuff like that) is simply and exactly equal to the convolution of vectors representing the probabilities of each face. The convolution of vectors is a summation -- it is a little tricky to get it right, but not too hard. Once you have that, you can handle any number of dice with any number of faces (and with different probabilities for each face if you want). I don't recommend VBA for this; can you use something else? If not, it is still possible. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well.. It sure gaves me something to study..

Answer (score 0):

It has been decades since I programmed in VBA, but what you want to do is use a [Collection object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object).  You can then iterate over a collection of dice, of any size, with loops that depend on the values of the dice.

What will be trickier is keeping track of the probabilities.  You can define a function that returns a variant, and then return an array of `Double`.  Which you can initialize to the right size with [ReDim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement).

By the time you figure all of this out, you will be a better VBA programmer.  However if you ever get to use a more flexible language, like Python, you'll quickly find out how much easier this all could be...

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I’ll try to figure out your answer for the next weeks 